# How do I create my own webapi action and call it using jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am learning ASP.NET MVC4 Web APIs.
I would like to create a new method that would be which receives two parameters

```
[HttpPost] 
public string MarkAsSeen(int objectID, long userID)
```

I would like to consume it using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/tutorial/MarkAsSeen",
        data: JSON.stringify({ objectID: _obj, profileID: _pid }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(_tutorial + ' seen');
        },async: true
});
```

I have my route configured this way

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

But it just doesn't work:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://local.dev.unation.com/api/tutorial/MarkAsSeen'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Tutorial' that matches the request.

IF I change the route's template to api/{controller}/{action}/{objectID}/{profileID} and the jquery method to add this info on the url: /api/tutorial/MarkAsSeen/ + _obj + / + _pid
it works.

I would not like to perform these changes because:

- I would like to have one general route to all actions (so their parameter names/quantity shouldn't matter)
- This url appending is just ugly, I would like to use the data attribute

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

tks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web.Api doesn't really like multiple parameters. The easiest solution is to create a new type which holds your data:

```
public class MarkAsSeenRequest
{
    public int objectID { get; set; }

    public int profileID { get; set; }
}
```

And use that in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost] 
public string MarkAsSeen(MarkAsSeenRequest request)
{
    //...
}
```

It should work fine with your original route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

For further reading:

- [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)
- [WebAPI Parameter binding under the hood](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx)
- [Sending HTML Form Data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1)

Comment: worked, thanks a lot, I would never find out this "trick" :) If it is a get request, how could I use this when calling using the url?

Comment: So if you want have a GET action with complex type parameter you need to use the `[FromUri]` attribute: `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet] public string MarkAsSeen([FromUri]MarkAsSeenRequest request) { }` then you can call this action with the url: e.g.  `/api/tutorial/MarkAsSeen?objectID=1&profileID=2`